# Angular jspdf-auotable with type definitions

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to use jspdf-autotable with jspdf. I have imported them like this:

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';
```

They both work. I have installed type definitions for jspdf which also work. However, I don't have the type definitions for jspdf-autotable. For example, I can't see the `autoTable` method on my `jsPDF` object, so my editor gives me an error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like `jspdf-autotable` does not have TypeScript definitions. Use the solution from https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/375

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I don't see how that solution helps me. Could you explain? jspdf-autotable works, but my editor is giving me an error.